# Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/GoogleUtils - in Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio

Can't figure out why I keep getting this error why trying to run application (it compiles fine)

```
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/GoogleUtils;
```

From the stack trace above I can say it stopped at:

```
/Users/jacek/Documents/GoW/myapp/build/pre-dexed/debug/support-v4-19.1.0-d45e513079f821d0bdcba2b3c444c8362d798113.jar
```

I think the next library it was going to generate was a dupplicate, but hard to say what was it...

Here are my dependencies:

dependencies {

```
    compile project(':pixlUI')
    compile project(':gowEndpoint')
    compile project(':messageEndpoint')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:4.0.1'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.1'
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.16.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.16.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.16.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.16.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-gson-1.16.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-jackson-1.16.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-jackson2-1.16.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.16.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some try-error I figured out that

```
compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar')
```

were dupplicates